# Whats wrong with an assignment

Tags: python, django, web

what's wrong?

`File "trunk/website/auth/user/emailchange/views.py" in email_change_view`
`102.     context['form'] = form`
`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in __setitem__`
`39.         self.dicts[-1][key] = value`

`Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/email/change/`
`Exception Value: 'SendUsernameForm' object does not support item assignment`

**Here is the Code**

```
else:
    form = EmailChangeForm(username=request.user.username)

context = RequestContext(request, extra_context)
context['form'] = form

return render_to_response(template_name, context_instance=context)
```

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Change email address" /></p>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `form` to `extra_context` dic, not `context`.

The error is literally saying, `context['form']` is invalid, so it's a good place to start wondering if RequestContext should be used in that fashion.

RequestContext docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

```
else:
    form = EmailChangeForm(username=request.user.username)

extra_context['form'] = form
context = RequestContext(request, extra_context)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working! But why should it not be used? Sorry, I am a newbee in Django and pyhton!

Comment: Why shouldn't it be used? Because it's not how the django developers built RequestContext to be used. PS: I wonder if something else was wrong with your code? Will you post your entire view? It sounds like you were passing in `SendUserNameForm` as `extra_context` instead of a `dict`